# inferred type is not accepted when included

Tags: haskell

A function which compiles and `cabal repl` even indicates what a specific type  should be (`rel`) produces an error if the inferred type is included in the code.

```
coords2faces  :: (MorphsHQ rel, Eq rel, Eq obj,   Ord obj)  => State (Store obj rel)  [(obj, obj)]
coords2faces = do 
    f <- rel3 (hqFace :: rel)
    return  f
```

How to include a type in code in such a case?

The error message is

```
app/TheMain.hs:107:16: error:
    • Could not deduce (MorphsHQ rel1) arising from a use of ‘hqFace’
      from the context: (MorphsHQ rel, Eq rel, Ord obj)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   coords2faces :: forall rel obj.
                                   (MorphsHQ rel, Eq rel, Eq obj, Ord obj) =>
                                   State (Store obj rel) [(obj, obj)]
        at app/TheMain.hs:105:1-98
      Possible fix:
        add (MorphsHQ rel1) to the context of
          an expression type signature:
            forall rel1. rel1
    • In the first argument of ‘rel3’, namely ‘(hqFace :: rel)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: f <- rel3 (hqFace :: rel)
      In the expression:
        do f <- rel3 (hqFace :: rel)
           return f
    |
107 |     f <- rel3 (hqFace :: rel)
```

Comment: You can remove the `Eq obj` constraint because it's implied by the `Ord obj` constraint. Also, according to the monad laws, there's no need to bind `f` and then `return` it again. You could just write `coords2faces = rel3 hqFace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `rel` in the type declared for `coords2faces` is not the same as the `rel` in the type declared for `hqFace`. To make this more obvious, you can see that the compiler renamed the type variable to `rel1` in the error message. By default, type variables in separate signatures are always independent.

In order to make the code compile, you can either remove the type signature for `hqFace`,

```
coords2faces :: (MorphsHQ rel, Eq rel, Eq obj, Ord obj) => State (Store obj rel) [(obj, obj)]
coords2faces = do
    f <- rel3 hqFace
    return f
```

or you can enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension and declare the `rel` type variable in a `forall` to specify the scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

coords2faces :: forall rel obj. (MorphsHQ rel, Eq rel, Eq obj, Ord obj) => State (Store obj rel) [(obj, obj)]
coords2faces = do 
    f <- rel3 (hqFace :: rel)
    return f
```

Comment: Thank you - I had never used `forall` and your answer made me read up the wiki and earlier discussions in SO. Now I understand a bit more and how `forall` is used with the `ScopedeTypeVariables` extension, which I had used already. (by the way, the compiler seemed to require `forall rel obj . `; perhaps you edit your answer?).

Comment: You can to write `rel3 @rel hqFace` or `rel3 (hqFace @rel)` (you may need to add a  in front of them: `rel3 @_ @rel ..`) with the language pragma `TypeApplications`. Here it doesn't matter but in more complicated types it provides a uniform way of instantiating type arguments